# If $|G|>1$ is not prime, there exists a subgroup of $G$ which is not $G$ or $e$.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

My question is in the title: Prove this statement.

Immediately before this question, I proved that $\langle g \rangle$ is a subgroup of $G$. The question specifies $G$ is a finite group.

My attempt:

By the previous question, provided that g is in G, then $\langle g \rangle$ is a subgroup of G. $\langle g\rangle$ is not the identity nor is it G itself unless G = $\langle g \rangle$ (in which case G is cyclic). So we can write $G = ${$e,g,g^2,...,g^{o(g)-1}$}.  If G is cyclic, it's order may be prime or non prime. For the purposes of the question, say |G| is nonprime. Then we can write a subgroup as {$g^n$}, where $0<n<o(g)$ so as to exclude the trivial case. Done (I think).

If |G| ≠ |$\langle g \rangle$|, and in particular, |G| < |$\langle g \rangle$| by Lagrange, then |G| is not prime (since it is not equal to it's cyclic group) and so $\langle g \rangle$ qualifies as a subgroup.$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\blacksquare$

Is it okay?

MASSIVE EDIT: Question should say |G|$> 1$ is NOT prime. Apologies.

Comment: The statement in the title is wrong.  Is it a typo?  (Side note: Many prefer that the content of the question doesn't depend on the title.  The title draws people in, hopefully gives a good idea of the content, but the body contains the full context, ideally.)

Comment: Thanks Jonas. I saw it just before your comment and put an edit into the content.

Comment: Please do edit ASAP your post's title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $|G|>1$ is not prime, say $|G|=ab$ with $a,b>1$.
Select $g\in G\setminus\{1\}$.
If $\langle g\rangle \ne G$, we are done.
Otherwise, the order of $g$ is $ab$ and we can consider $\langle g^a\rangle$ instead, which has order $b$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how if the order of G is $ab$ then a subgroup is necessarily $\langle g^a \rangle$ which has order $b$?  Is it a consequence of Lagrange, i.e the order has to divide the order of G? Why must we have $\langle g^a \rangle$ then?

Comment: Actually I think I understand.  If $<g^a>$ has order $b$ then $<(g^a)^b> =  <(g^{ab})> = <(g^{|G|})> = e$.  (One element must have an order |G|).  Is this correct?

Comment: Can any of you explain to me mathematically, why <g> not equal to G should be obvious. The way I see it is. G is not cyclic, so there is no g in G such that <g> = G. Now, <g> can be a subgroup of just identity element, but how does this exactly tell me that other subgroup/s of order not equal to |G| exist?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the subgroup $H$ generated by an element $g\ne e$ is a good idea. Perhaps this group is a proper subgroup. Then we are finished.

If $H$ is all of $G$, let $|G|=ab$ where neither $a$ nor $b$ is $1$, and consider the group generated by $g^a$. That seems to be what you were thinking of, but one needs to *prove* that under these conditions the group generated by $g^a$ is indeed a *proper* subgroup.

If instead we consider the subgroup generated by $g^n$, where we only specify that $1\lt n\lt |G|$, then this subgroup is *often* all of $G$. In fact it is all of $G$ precisely if $|G|$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Okay thanks.  One question just to check I am not confused: G can only have one cyclic group right? The $<g^a>$ above is a cyclic group but because it's order is less than the order of <g> it is not equal to <g>

Comment: I don't know what ou mean. A group can have many cyclic subgroups. This discussion is getting kind of long, the system objects. I will delete most of my previous comments, suggest you do the same. That will leave room for more, if necessary!

Comment: A group can have many cyclic subgroups, I understand this, but say, when I write G = <g>, is this <g> unique?

Comment: Also, when in the proof did I make explicit that |G| was non-prime?

Comment: Well, you didn't, but the your original proof is not correct. Remember we only need to worry if $G$ is cyclic with generator $g$. Then we need to produce a proper subgroup. So we are looking at the case $|G|=m$, where $m$ is the order of $g$. We use the fact $m$ is not prime by writing $m=ab$ where neither $a$ nor $b$ is $1$. Then we prove that the group generated by $g^a$ is a proper subgroup of the group generated by $g$.

Comment: Think more concretely. A cyclic group of size $m$ is isomorphic to the integers $0$ to $m-1$ under addition mod $m$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:Let $o(G)=mn$ then one subgroup is $<g^m>$.

Answer (score 2):

You write:

- $\langle g\rangle$ is not the identity nor is it $G$ itself unless $G = \langle g\rangle$

but then you never address the case that $G = \langle g\rangle$.  Why do you assume that this is not the case?

In fact the statement in your title is false, if $|G| > 1$ is prime then $G \simeq \mathbb Z/p$ and any non-identity element generates all of $G$.

Edit:

$|G|$ **not** prime makes much more sense as a question :)

With your edit, the problem I still see in your proof is that you say $\langle g^n\rangle \neq G$ is a subgroup for $n < |G|$ but this is not true for any arbitrary $n$.  You have to show how to pick such an $n$ and why that particular $n$ works.

Comment: @CAF: Do your claim in the title, for $G=\{0,1\}$. Can you get any other proper subgroup? ;-)

Comment: Hi Jim. I will correct the title but I put an edit in the content.  It should say |G| > 1 is NOT prime. In terms of addressing $G = \langle g \rangle$, I said if this was the case then any element in $<g>$(=G) can form a subgroup.  Is there something else I should add?.

Comment: Yes, when $G$ is cyclic you should say how to pick $g$, because for some $g$ you will get $\langle g \rangle = 1$ or $= G$.

Comment: Did I not write that $0<n<o(g)$, i.e exclude the identity and G itself?

Comment: You did write that but it's not correct.  For example assume $G = \langle g\rangle$ is cyclic and $|G| = 4$.  Then $\langle g^3\rangle = G$ even though $0 < 3 < 4$.

Comment: Could you explain why $\langle g^3 \rangle$ =G

Comment: Because $g^4 = 1$ so $g^3 = g^{-1}$.  Hence $\langle g^3\rangle = \langle g^{-1}\rangle$ and for any $g$ we have $\langle g\rangle = \langle g^{-1}\rangle$.  To convince yourself try calculating successive powers of $g^3$, you'll find that all $4$ elements of $G$ appear.

Comment: Just a quick question about manipulation.  If I take, $<g^3>$, for example, then I have $<g^{-1} g^{-1} g^{-1}> = <g^{-3}>$ which is not right. What is the correct way to manipulate?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "manipulate".  What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: I am trying to take the powers of g.  For example, $gg = g^2$, $g^2g = g^3$ but when I apply this to $(g^{-1})^3$ say, I get $g^{-3}$, but I don't think that is right.

Comment: That is right, but remember $g^4 = 1$ so $g^{-3} = 1\cdot g^{-3} = g^4\cdot g^{-3} = g$.

Answer (score 1):

Just for clarity's sake, here is the proof that if $g$ generates $G$, and $|G| = mn,\ 1 < m,n < |G|$, that $1 < |\langle g^m \rangle| < |G|$.

If $|\langle g^m \rangle| = 1$ then $g^m = e$ contradicting that $|g| = |G| = mn$.

Since $e = g^{mn} = (g^m)^n$, we must have $|g^m| \leq n < mn = |G|$.

One can indeed prove that $|g^m| = n$ but this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with stating that for $g \in G$ we know that $\langle g \rangle \leq G$. At this stage, we either have $\langle g \rangle < G$ is a proper subgroup as you desire, or $G$ is cyclic and $\langle g \rangle = G$.

Let us denote $|G|=mn$ for $m,n >1$. In the case where $G$ is cyclic, then consider the element $g^m \in G$. We can now generate a new cyclic subgroup with this element, $\langle g^m \rangle$.

It is known that $g^{|G|} = e \;\;\forall g \in G$. Thus,

$$g^{mn}=e \implies (g^m)^n=e \implies o(g^m)=n$$

We also know that the order of a cyclic subgroup is equal to the order of the generating element, thus:

$$|\langle g^m \rangle|=n<|G|$$

Now, we have a proper cyclic subgroup strictly not equal to $G$, thus you have proved what was asked of you.